# Building a patched Openssl 1.1.1a with Visual Studio under Windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio, openssl

I try to build a patched Openssl 1.1.1a with Visual Studio under Windows.
The patches adds some functions to the original Openssl code. With Linux the compiling and linking works just fine. On Windows I have some trouble with unresolved external symbols for every added function from my patches.

```
perl Configure no-asm VC-WIN32 
nmake

1>libcrypto.def : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol BUF_MEM_print
1>libcrypto.def : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol CA_CTX_new
1>libcrypto.def : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol CA_STEP1_get_pubkey
```

The `libcrypto.def`file seems to be generated from some perl scripts. On Linux its just sufficant to execute:

```
make update
```

to update the def files for sucessfull linking.

on windows I tried to execute this to achieve the same:

```
perl util\mkdef.pl crypto update
perl util\mkdef.pl ssl update
```

But this won't work, Some ideas what to do here?

Comment: did you try to clean intermediates files (nmake clean) before building ?

Comment: yes I did `nmake clean` before. I by passed the problem by using  option`no-shared`